# jquery function problem

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

I have this function

```
function onclickRowRecord(recordID) { 

     $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: '/file/to/post.to.php' ,
   data: {recordID:recordID}, 
   success: function(data) {

    //how to post this to  function howToPost(recordID) the recordID  

   }
  });        
} 

function howToPost(recordID){
alert(recordID);
}
```

so how can I get the response from ajax success and post to the other function

Comment: I assume you've tried calling it from within the success block (e.g. function(data) { howToPost(data); } )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If post you mean call the hotToPost function, then

```
...
success: function(data) {

    howToPost(data.recordID); //or whatever

}
....
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", url: '/file/to/post.to.php' , data: {recordID:recordID}, success: function(data) {
        alert(recordID)
    } 
});
```

Does that work? Kinda new to jQuery